# Copying StreamReader contents to Output Stream - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: .net, vb.net

So I have the following extension method:

```
 <Extension()> _
    Public Sub CopyTo(ByVal inputStream As StreamReader, ByVal outputStream As Stream)
        Dim buffer As Char() = New Char(8 * 1024 - 1) {}
        Dim len As Integer
        Do
            len = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            Dim bytes() As Byte = inputStream.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(buffer)
            If len > 0 Then outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, len)
        Loop While len > 0
    End Sub
```

It doesn't work because it seems to not copy the last X number of characters from a stream to an output stream. Just can't think of why.

The following seems to work fine:

```
 <Extension()> _
    Public Sub CopyTo(ByVal inputStream As StreamReader, ByVal outputStream As Stream)
        Dim ftext As String = inputStream.ReadToEnd()
        Dim bytes() As Byte = inputStream.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(ftext.ToCharArray)
        outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    End Sub
```

Why is my first extension method not copying the last X characters (seems mostly to not copy the last character of the file + <CR><LF> (total 3 characters)?

Comment: The *first* thing I'd change is the parameter name. Calling a `StreamReader` variable `inputStream` is inappropriate - it suggests that it's a `Stream`, not a `TextReader`.

Comment: If all you want to do is copy an input stream to an output stream, look at the [`Stream.CopyTo()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: The number of Bytes you are writing is `len` but that is the number of Chars. Depending on the encoding, a Char may be more than one Byte.

Comment: @JonSkeet: sorry, copy and paste wins again. I actually call it "reader" in the real method but good catch :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the variable `len` for two different purposes, that <s>**could**</s> **will** conflict.

You will need to change this part:

```
len = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
Dim bytes() As Byte = inputStream.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(buffer)
If len > 0 Then outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, len)
```

To

```
len = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
If (len > 0) Then
    Dim bytes() As Byte = inputStream.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(buffer, 0, len)
    outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
End If
```

If all you really want to do is copy the entire input stream from source to destination, use the [`Stream.CopyTo` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to do that.

Comment: Yup, that looks right. Thanks! Knew it had to be something silly.

Comment: Would love to use Stream.CopyTo() but we're still on .NET 3.5 and that is a .NET 4.0 feature. The above is my adaptation until we migrate.

Comment: @Denis if you search for it, you will likely find implementations of a `CopyTo` extension method on `Stream` used by other people still targeting earlier .NET versions.

Comment: @Denis as Alex pointed out stream level Copy would be much easier and safer even if you can't use `Stream.CopyTo`. For example your current code looses BOM (as it is not exposes by reader).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issues are

- `CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(buffer)`: last read does not fill whole buffer, so you essentially writing random data for last block.
- `outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, len)` - uses number of characters instead `bytes.Length`, so writes wrong number of bytes (would work for ASCII, anything outside of the range will throw it off)
- possibly not closing/flushing stream (unlikely as eventually it'll be closed).

Fix - pass actual number of characters using other override of [`GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ydktsz9z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = inputStream.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(buffer, 0, len)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to flush the stream.